# Android - Display all images from server folder using PHP in GridView

Tags: php, android, android-service, android-camera, android-imageview

I am trying to capture image or record a video using camera and then upload to my server. On the server side, i used PHP language to read the file and moved it to a particular location. Now i want to display all these images that are stored my server. Please help me.

This is the upload image PHP script

```js
<?php
 
// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";
 
// array for final json respone
$response = array();
 
// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
 
// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;
 
 
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
 
    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';
 
    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;
 
    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }
 
        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}
 
// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

upload Camera image:

[image]

[image]

i want to display theses images synchronised when i upload images again.

**Config.java**

```js
public class Config {
// File upload url (replace the ip with your server address)
public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://wangjian.site90.net/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php";
// Directory name to store captured images and videos
public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
```

I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. thanks so much! And i will upload more details if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Have an API endpoint return the URLs of the images that you have uploaded and then call them from the app.

Like,

```
public static final String FILE_DOWNLOAD_URL = "http://wangjian.site90.net/AndroidFileUpload/getUserPhotos.php";
```

Let this return some JSON Array like,

```
{
   "urls" : [
     {   
        "url" : "url of pic 1"
     },
     {
        "url" : "url of pic 2"
     },
     ..
    ]
}
```

Have a custom `GridAdpater` with an `ImageView` in it. Use libraries like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the images from the url into your `GridView` using the custom adapter with a custom view (Here, `ImageView`).

Call this API endpoint every time when the user is on the screen so that you'll be able to fetch the list of uploaded photos and show them everytime.

Comment: Yes, man i know use json to transfrom data, but this way with a series of complex methods by manage this app, i want to easier like when user upload photo, the image uploding to imageview is automated. Anyway thanks bro